# Adding <description> metadata in php / html for google results page

Tags: php, html, google, search-results

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Does Google use the Meta Description Tag for Description of Page?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/15973/does-google-use-the-meta-description-tag-for-description-of-page)

I've got a simple website that uses a php script to geolocate a user's IP and redirect accordingly - UK users get sent to the .co.uk html site, while everyone else gets sent to the .com.

Whenever the site shows up in google, however, the description is completely blank. I've tried adding  tags to the html, and also via echo in the php, but still nothing shows up. The site's been up for a few months, so it's been well crawled and scores pretty highly for some search terms.

Any ideas how i can get a description up on the SERPs? Thanks!

Comment: Google has it's own way of creating the description, there is no specifc way you can trigger the generation of the description. Look on their homepage, they should explain that in length.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you are not using the correct meta element?

```
<meta name="description" content="This is the description">
```

http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?answer=35624

Answer (score 1):

This question at Pro Webmaster covers how Google chooses what to display in its search results: [Does Google use the Meta Description Tag for Description of Page?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/15973/does-google-use-the-meta-description-tag-for-description-of-page/)