# no description when searching keyword in google

Tags: seo, google, keywords, google-index, meta-description

I am new with SEO, and i following a tutorial about meta tags...
when i search my keyword in Google, I can only see the URL of my website but it has no description....

```
 search in google: surebooked
---------------------------------
 but return only: surebooked.com/
```

There are no description in Google when I search my keyword. Does anyone have an idea about my situation?

Comment: Are you using a content management system or just static html pages?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does Google use the Meta Description Tag for Description of Page?](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/15973/does-google-use-the-meta-description-tag-for-description-of-page)

Comment: @toomanyairmiles, I am using django in my website...

Comment: @gadss this might point you in the right direction then http://www.yeago.net/blog/2010/jul/20/django-meta-tag-management/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google can actually display whatever it likes in the search results i.e. what it thinks is relevant to the most common queries about that page/site/file/whatever but most often it goes with whats in your meta title and meta description tags e.g.

**Daily Telegraph Google Result**

[image: Daily Telegraph Homepage result from google]

**Corresponding meta tags**

```
<title>News - Latest breaking news - Telegraph</title>
<meta name="description" content="Latest news, breaking news and current news from the UK and around the world, plus celebrity news and political news from Telegraph.co.uk, all the latest breaking stories" />
```

So you need to insert these two meta tags into the `<head></head>` section of each of your HTML pages, it is best to have unique content about each page in them, rather than the same text repeated over and over again.

Answer (score 0):

Check your meta description tag. Does it exist in the front page? Maybe some script or something is preventing to appear.

Answer (score 0):

Is this the code you entered?

```
<title>BBC - Homepage</title>
<meta name="description" content="Breaking news, sport, TV, radio and a whole lot more. The BBC informs, educates and entertains - wherever you are, whatever your age.">
<meta name="keywords" content="BBC, bbc.co.uk, bbc.com, Search, British Broadcasting Corporation, BBC iPlayer, BBCi">
```

The contents and title changes...

Answer (score 0):

I'm getting the correct page description that's in the source code of the main page.
Since I'm new I can't upload screenshots but it all looks fine from where I'm sitting.