# Strange description appearing in Google search results

Tags: google-search, search

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Does Google use the Meta Description Tag for Description of Page?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/15973/does-google-use-the-meta-description-tag-for-description-of-page)

I just noticed that when searching Google for the name of a website I'm working on, the search result description now has a broken English phrase which does not appear anywhere on that website, nor on the Google Places page:

[image: Screenshot of Google search result: "Company builds blogs and custom plug in software for the sites." ...?]

Where might this text be coming from?  How can I fix it?

Answer (score 2):

Google couldn't find the `<meta name="description" value="value here!">`, so he picks an old one or generates one himself.

Answer (score 2):

I believe what you are seeing in the description of the company on Dmoz. You should be able to use the noodp tag to get it removed.

Answer (score 1):

Google can actually display whatever it likes in the search results i.e. what it thinks is relevant to the most common queries about that page/site/file/whatever but most often it goes with whats in your meta title and meta description tags e.g.

**Daily Telegraph Google Result**

[image: Daily Telegraph Homepage result from google]

**Corresponding meta tags**

```
<title>News - Latest breaking news - Telegraph</title>
<meta name="description" content="Latest news, breaking news and current news from the UK and around the world, plus celebrity news and political news from Telegraph.co.uk, all the latest breaking stories" />
```

So you need to insert these two meta tags into the `<head></head>` section of each of your HTML pages, it is best to have unique content about each page in them, rather than the same text repeated over and over again.

@Joshak's answer shows exactly where this particular description is coming from and how to change it on DMOZ, my answer tells you how you fix your site.

I would also recommend implementing [google webmaster tools](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/home?hl=en) as it will help alert google to the changes to your page and give you a better idea about what google knows about your site.