# Why Google skips page title

Tags: google, seo, google-index

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Does Google use the Meta Description Tag for Description of Page?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/15973/does-google-use-the-meta-description-tag-for-description-of-page)

I have no idea why this is happening.

Title tag is:
Unfurnished Office Space Wimbledon – Serviced Office on Lombard Road SW19

But is indexed as:
Lombard Road – SW19 - London Office Space

If you look in the source code and search for this portion ‘Lombard Road – SW19’
You then find that it's next to an office image
alt=’Lombard Road – SW19’.

The only thing I could think of is that the spider somehow ‘skips’ our title tag and grabs this bit, and then inserts the name of the site (but WHY?)

Is there anything I can do with this? or is this a Google behaviour?

Comment: Can't find the image alt text you are referring to. An older cached version of the page, perhaps?

Comment: Also, page layout with tables?! It's 2012! :-)

Comment: @DavidJohnWelsh - You can find the alt text on the map image. This is not an older cached version. And I am experiencing the same thing in quite a few of other office pages. Hmm I know this is an outdated page layout as this is an old site.

Comment: Ah, yes. For some reason the Chrome dev tools search didn't find it when I tried before, but I see it now. The only reason for it I can imagine is that Google infers from the fact that there is a pinpointed place on one of its maps that the page is about that place, and that is therefore the most useful information. Does seem *really* bizarre to use that over the `<title>` though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This might help:

http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=35624

It appears that it *is* a Google behaviour. The title tag may not be descriptive enough - maybe there are lots of other pages on the site with similar titles...?

**EDIT:**

Specifically (quoting from the above page):

> If we’ve detected that a particular result has one of the above issues
>   with its title, we may try to generate an improved title from anchors,
>   on-page text, or other sources. However, sometimes even pages with
>   well-formulated, concise, descriptive titles will end up with
>   different titles in our search results to better indicate their
>   relevance to the query. There’s a simple reason for this: the title
>   tag as specified by a webmaster is limited to being static, fixed
>   regardless of the query. Once we know the user’s query, **we can often
>   find alternative text from a page that better explains why that result
>   is relevant**. Using this alternative text as a title helps the user,
>   and it also can help your site. Users are scanning for their query
>   terms or other signs of relevance in the results, and a title that is
>   tailored for the query can increase the chances that they will click
>   through.
>
> If you’re seeing your pages appear in the search results with modified
>   titles, check whether your titles have one of the problems described
>   above. If not, consider whether the alternate title is a better fit
>   for the query. **If you still think the original title would be better,
>   let us know in our Webmaster Help Forum**.