# Google displaying wrong site title and snippet

Tags: google, google-search, web-crawlers, spam, spam-prevention

I am having an issue where a website that displays the incorrect site title and snippet in Google Search.

From the content it is clear that some spammer has infected the site, but I cannot figure out how it is being done. I deleted all of the website files and uploaded an earlier backup, then resubmitted it through Webmaster tools. But the problem still persists.

I've been through all the pages and can't see anything dodgy in the code. Can anyone see what I'm missing?

Many thanks

Comment: See also: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/15973/does-google-use-the-meta-description-tag-for-description-of-page

Comment: @JohnConde This is very much a different question than title tags and such. It appears that the site was hacked or compromised. Following the Google link makes it clear what the OP is talking about.

Comment: What CMS are you using? As well what is the web server? What are the versions of each? Are there other services running on that computer such as DNS, FTP, SMTP, etc. If they are being used, fine; but if not, you may want to shut them down. Make sure everything is up to date at least. If you are using a CMS, what **plug-ins and themes** are you using and versions?

Comment: @closetnoc, while the situation may be different the outcome is the same. The infected situation changed the title tag, Ember just needs to wait for Google to update, doing a fetch, or resubmission won't trigger the update, time does.

Comment: @SimonHayter I am seeing the question being *Can anyone see what I'm missing?* My answer is: *Yeah. You were hacked!*